# Why the red layer is displayed on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a calendar widget.
We added a DecoratedBox wrapped in Expanded in the Row header of the day of the week.
Why is a red layer displayed when using Expanded?

When Expanded is excluded, DecoratedBox is not expanded...

[image]

```
class CalenderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalenderPageState createState() => new _CalenderPageState();
}

class _CalenderPageState extends State<CalenderPage> {
  DateTime now = new DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Calender'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: _createWeekOfDays()),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _createWeekOfDays() {
    List<Widget> _weekOfDays = new List<Widget>();
    for (final weekOfDay in ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun',]) {
      _weekOfDays.add(
        new Expanded(
          child: new DecoratedBox(
            position: DecorationPosition.background,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              border: new Border.all(
                  color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor, width: 1.0),
            ),
            child: new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
              child: new Text(
                weekOfDay,
                style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return _weekOfDays;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an overflow problem;

**You can wrap your `Row` inside a fixed `width` `Container`**

```
body: new Center(
        child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            width: 320.0,
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: _createWeekOfDays())),
        ]),
      ),
```

**Or you can wrap your `Row` within `Padding` widget, and indent the area on the right so it does not overflow on the edge of the screen**

```
body: new Center(
        child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),
              child: new Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: _createWeekOfDays())),
        ]),
      ),
```

**Alternatively, you can use `ListView` and specify the the size of the `Container` such that the whole view is shown without the need to scroll, but here you will need to modify the design of your layout a little bit**

I have added a piece of code that might help you:

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Calender'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
          height: 50.0,
          child: new ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: new List.generate(7, (int index) {
              return new Card(
                child: new Container(
                      width: 43.0,
                      height: 30.0,
                      child: new Center(
                          child: new Text(_daysOfWeek(index))),
                    ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
    _daysOfWeek(int index) {
    List myWeek = new List<String>(7);
    myWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun',];
    return myWeek[index];
  }
}
```